# 3D Secure request sending using php

Tags: php, xml, 3d-secure

I am trying to implement 3d secure. I have a xml containing some data as required by  3d secure.Like :

```
<CardinalMPI>
<MsgType>cmpi_lookup</MsgType>
<Version>1.7</Version>
<ProcessorId>xxx</ProcessorId>
<MerchantId>xxxxxx</MerchantId>
<TransactionPwd>xxxxxxxxxxx</TransactionPwd>
<TransactionType>C</TransactionType>
<Amount>56999</Amount>
<CurrencyCode>xxxxx</CurrencyCode>
<OrderNumber>xxxx</OrderNumber>
<CardNumber>xxx</CardNumber>
<CardExpMonth>xxx</CardExpMonth>
<CardExpYear>xxx</CardExpYear>
</CardinalMPI>
```

Then how can I request to http://msgtest.bankserv.co.za/maps/txns.asp   with above xml and get their response back ? I tried curl, Soap etc and got error. Please help me with some answers in detail.

I have tried the following codes. Please let me know if this code is not correct.

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openMemory();

$writer->startElement("CardinalMPI");
$writer->writeElement("MsgType","cmpi_lookup");
$writer->writeElement("Version","1.7");
$writer->writeElement("ProcessorId","xxxxx");
$writer->writeElement("MerchantId","xxxxxxx");
$writer->writeElement("TransactionPwd","xxxxx");
$writer->writeElement("TransactionType","C");
$writer->writeElement("Amount",$xxxx);
$writer->writeElement("CurrencyCode","xxxx");
$writer->writeElement("OrderNumber","xxxxxxxxxx");
$writer->writeElement("CardNumber","'xxxxxxxxx");
$writer->writeElement("CardExpMonth","xx");
$writer->writeElement("CardExpYear","xxxx");
$writer->endElement();
$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
$request = $writer->outputMemory(true);

$serviceArguments =       array("validateRequest"=>"0","protocol"=>"v_xml","protocolVersion"=>"2.0","request"=> $request);
$client = new SoapClient("msgtest.bankserv.co.za/maps/txns.asp", array('local_cert'=> "certificate.pem"));
$result = $client->Execute($serviceArguments);
$xml=$result->ExecuteResult;
```

When I am running this code I am getting exceptions.

Comment: Can we see your cURL and SOAP solutions? We might be able to help fix what you've tried. (Edit one of them into your question, and provide the error message relating to that script in the question text too, if you would).

Comment: I can't be the only one here who is slightly concerned that you are unable to resolve this yourself and are handling sensitive credit card details...

Comment: @Tomdarkness, you are not, web-development is still treated like some kind of hobby any one with a computer can do, and not a true profession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posting values we can make use of CURL in php. Here you can use :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "your url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "yr_variable=".$your xml);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```